# Conditional Async Waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async.js

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363965/nodejs-and-async-waterfall-with-if-conditions-and-conditional-function-list), which has async waterfall based on a condition inside another parent waterfall.

How would the arguments passing work while passing arguments to the `function(condition, callback){}` in the following.

```
  async.waterfall([
     callOne,
     callTwo,
     function (condition, callback) {
        if (condition > 0) {
            async.waterfall([
                callTest1
            ], callback);
        } else {
            async.waterfall([
                callTest3,
                callTest4
            ], callback);
        }
    },
    callThree,
    callFour,
    callFive,
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).jsonp({error: err});
    }
});
```

Q1. I want to pass arguments returned by `callTwo` to `callTest1`

Q2. Also do I have to use `async.waterfall()` within the `if` condition if i just have one function to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used async.apply to pass the arguments to the callTest1 function.
eg: `async.apply(callTest1.bind(self), arg1, arg2)`

where `callTest1` takes arguments in the order: `(arg1, arg2, callback)`